# Bing Maps custom NavBar textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

**I'm interested in adding a textbox (and button) to the Default navigation bar in Bing Maps v7.**

My intent is to add a place-name geocoder to help the user quickly zoom to a specific area on the map.  (This is a service provided by Bing Maps API, I just need help adding the box to the control.)  I can, but don't have to, use jQuery.

The website http://pietschsoft.com/post/2010/12/18/Bing-Maps-Ajax-7-Add-Custom-Navigation-Bar-Buttons-using-jQuery.aspx actually has some really great sample code showing how to add a button to the bar, though I can't seem to get a textbox to work properly.  My suspicion is that Bing Maps is hijacking all of my key-presses to use for panning, etc., but I'm not positive.

Has anybody had any luck in doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting an another div with the same background color and height, floating left at an x-offset of the width of the original navbar.  The keypresses *were* being hijacked - it seems they've stolen all keyboard input for any elements that exist within the "Microsoft.Map" div.  My div is one level higher up.

Here's how it turned out:
[image]

And if anyone's interested, the default height and color for the Bing Maps v7 navbar is 26px, #FAF7F5.

Comment: up one vote for "The keypresses were being hijacked - it seems they've stolen all keyboard input for any elements that exist within the "Microsoft.Map" div". I concur